# How can I rotate a model, apply that rotation, and then rotate it back?

Tags: python, blender

I'd like to spin a model by 90 degrees by the x axis, apply that rotation, then do exactly the same for the y and z axis. After that, I need to spin the model back. I figured that just applying the opposite rotation to each axis would do the trick, but that apparently won't do the trick...

What's really frustrating is that the "broken" part of the code is that I'm applying the first round of rotations. If I do the exact same process by hand though, I don't have this issue. If I don't apply the rotations, this code is useless to me (I'm using it to get the z-bounds for each consecutive rotation)

```
import bpy
import math

model = bpy.data.objects['model']

zmax = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range(3):

    zmax[i] = model.dimensions[2] 

    model.rotation_euler[i] += math.pi/2            #rotate

    model.select_set(True)                          #select model
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation=True)   #apply rot

for i in range(3):
    model.rotation_euler[i] -= math.pi/2            #rotate to original posi
```

The model seems to just spin around one axis, I can't confirm this for sure though. If you run the script enough times, it will eventually end up in the same spot.

Comment: If you cannot find help here you may also consider posting your question to [Blender SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not an expert with Blender scripting but a rotation can happen relative to world space or object space. Maybe you use the wrong one.

Comment: How are your steps any different than just reading the three dimensions values in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

Quickly answering my own question for anyone in the future that might stumble upon this: The answer lies in using quaternion rotations instead. Everything else can be done the same, but if you're doing complex rotations, you must use quaternions instead of degrees.